# features' importances Random Forest

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest

I got the feautures' importances by `scikit-learn`'s random forest regressor in python, but I don't understand how it's calculated.

I have two questions below,

1. In the case of classification, I guess the importance are decided by the reduction of Gini coefficient. But considering the ensemble, how does this merge the output(feautures' importances) from so many trees? Is it simple average?
2. In the case of regressor, how does it judge the importance? By the reduction of MSE or something?

Sorry I'm struggling for getting the definition in Scikit-learn official.